# Nested modular subroutines where the inner subroutine changes

Tags: perl, perl-module, subroutine

I have a sub that reads a [FASTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) text file in chunks.

```
sub reader {
    foreach my $line (<IN>) {   # read line by line
        chomp $line;
        if ($line =~ m/^>/) {   # if it's a title
            &initiator($title, $seq) unless $firsttitle == 1;
            $firsttitle = 0;
            ($title = $line) =~ s/^>//; # title without > at start
            $seq = '';  # new seq
        } else {
            $seq = $seq . $line;    # append seq lines
        }
    }
    &initiator($title, $seq);   # Do the thing for the last seq.
}
```

In the middle of several loops, &initiator is called. I'd like to have this in a module that I can "use" but substitute &initiator with other subs from other modules. These subs will need to have their own inputs as well. Would something like the following work or is there a more elegant solution?

```
use Reader qw(reader);
use Othersub qw(subroutine);
my @par = ('Mary', 'Lamb');
my %functions = (foo => \&Othersub::subroutine);
&reader($file_to_read, $functions{'foo'}($par[0], $par[1]));
```

Note: Final file structure is Othersub.pm, Reader.pm and the script that uses both modules.

Comment: What do you mean by "need to have their own inputs"? Do you mean, these functions have different input parameters than `&initiator`?
Because, in this case, what sense does it make to pass that function (_function reference_, to be precise),  to reader?

Comment: Prefixing functions with `&` is deprecated in the current version of perl. It has a rather specific meaning now, and _at best_ it's redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl allows you to create references to things, and that includes both subroutines and arrays.

If you've got differing arguments to pass, then I would suggest you want to do so via array reference rather than what you're doing. A bit like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub variable_args {
    my ( $code_ref, $array_ref ) = @_;
    #dereference code ref;
    #dereference array ref;
    &$code_ref( @$array_ref, "optional", "extra", "arg" );
}

sub foo_func {
    foreach (@_) {
        print "Foo $_\n";
    }
}

sub bar_func {
    print "BAR: ", join( ":", @_ ), "\n";
}


#could inline the functions as anonymous subs. I would avoid doing that
#unless they're pretty short/clear. 
my %functions = (
    'foo' => \&foo_func,
    'bar' => \&bar_func,
);

my %args_to_pass = (
    'foo' => [ "Mary", "Lamb" ],
    'bar' => [ "Some", "Fish", "Pie" ],
);


for my $thing ( "foo", "bar" ) {
    variable_args( $functions{$thing}, $args_to_pass{$thing} );
}
```

Note - in the example above, you call `&initiator`. You shouldn't do this. It's deprecated syntax from Perl 4, and is redundant (and may have some undesired consequences in certain scenarios).

But I would suggest doing it this way rather than the way you've got. You *could* get this to work:

```
&reader($file_to_read, $functions{'foo'}($par[0], $par[1]));
```

But what will happen when you try and do that is you'll (potentially) just run your function immediately, and pass it's result into `reader`.

E.g.:

```
variable_args ( &{$functions{'foo'}}("Mary", "Lamb"), ["more stuff"] );
```

Won't work, because you're 'running' it immediately, and then sending the result - which'll make your `$code_ref` whatever the *result* of the subroutine was.

However you *could* make an anonymous sub, and pass that:

```
variable_args( sub {
                     &{ $functions{'foo'} }( "Special", "Argument", @_ ) 
                   },
               $args_to_pass{'foo'} );
```

I would suggest you're getting needlessly convoluted by that point though :)

Comment: Thanks for the info! It was really comprehensive and informative.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can guess, you want to pass a function (reference) as parameter.
Something like this should work for you

```
# Script

use Reader qw(reader);
use Othersub qw(subroutine);

my @par = .... ; 
reader( $file_to_read , \&subroutine , @par);

# Reader.pm

sub reader {
    my $file = shift;
    my $initiator = shift;
    my @par = @_; 
    ...
    $initiator->( $file , @par)
    ...
}
```

*Remark:* In the last line of your code, you are not passing the function `subroutine` to `reader`, as you might have intendend; instead, you invoke it and pass *the result of soubroutine, given the paramers par* to reader.